# How to make FPS crawl?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity New Input System for my FPS game and I have figured out the movement and the mouselook. However, I'm trying to add a crawling feature to my moving script. I don't want the player to be holding down a button for crawling, it would be better to click a button to change the status from walking to crawling and then just move accordingly. and of course, the mouselook will differ in every state. How would I achieve that with the minimal code changes?

[image]

`Movement` class:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] CharacterController controller;
    [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float runSpeed = 35f;
    float moveSpeed; 
    Vector2 horizontalInput; 
    [SerializeField] float jumpHeight = 3.5f;
    bool jump, running;
    [SerializeField] float gravity = -30f; //-9.81
    Vector3 verticalVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundMask;
    bool isGrounded;
    Vector3 horizontalVelocity;



    private void Update()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, 0.1f, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity.y = 0; 
         }
        // Jump: v = sqrt(-2 * jumpheight* gravity)
        if (jump)
        {
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                verticalVelocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(-2f * jumpHeight * gravity); 
            }
            jump = false;
        }
        verticalVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(verticalVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (running)
        {
            moveSpeed = runSpeed;
            horizontalVelocity = (transform.right * horizontalInput.x + transform.forward * horizontalInput.y) * moveSpeed;
            controller.Move(horizontalVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
            horizontalVelocity = (transform.right * horizontalInput.x + transform.forward * horizontalInput.y) * moveSpeed;
            controller.Move(horizontalVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    public void ReceiveInput(Vector2 _horizontalInput)
    {
        horizontalInput = _horizontalInput;
    }
    public void OnJumpPressed() 
    {
        jump = true; 
    }

    public void OnRunningPressed() {
        running = true;
    }
   
}
```

`MouseLook` class:

```
 public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] float sensitivityX = 8f;
        [SerializeField] float sensitivityY = 0.5f;
        float mouseX, mouseY;
    
        [SerializeField] Transform playerCamera;
        [SerializeField] float xClamp = 75f;
        float xRotataion = 0f; 
    
        private void Update()
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseX * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            xRotataion -= mouseY;
            xRotataion = Mathf.Clamp(xRotataion, -xClamp, xClamp);
            Vector3 targetRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
            targetRotation.x = xRotataion;
            playerCamera.eulerAngles = targetRotation;
        }
        public void ReceiveInput(Vector2 mouseInput) 
        {
            mouseX = mouseInput.x * sensitivityX;
            mouseY = mouseInput.y * sensitivityY;
        }
    }
```

`InputManager` class:

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Movement movement;
    [SerializeField] PlayerInteractions playerInteractions;
    [SerializeField] MouseLook mouseLook;
    PlayerControls controls; 
    PlayerControls.GroundMovementActions groundMovement;
    Vector2 horizontalInput;
    Vector2 mouseInput;

    private void Awake() 
  {
        controls = new PlayerControls(); 
        groundMovement = controls.GroundMovement;
        // groundMovement.[action].performed += context => do something
        groundMovement.HorizontalMovement.performed += ctx => horizontalInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        groundMovement.Jump.performed += _ => movement.OnJumpPressed();
        groundMovement.Running.performed += _ => movement.OnRunningPressed();
        groundMovement.PickingUp.performed += _ => playerInteractions.OnPickingUp();
        groundMovement.MouseX.performed += ctx => mouseInput.x = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
        groundMovement.MouseY.performed += ctx => mouseInput.y = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
        groundMovement.Open.performed += _ => playerInteractions.OnOpenPressed(); 
       
    }   

    private void Update()
    {
        movement.ReceiveInput(horizontalInput);
        mouseLook.ReceiveInput(mouseInput); 
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable(); 
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        controls.Disable(); 
    }
}
```

I failed to find anything like this online and I don't know how to achieve it using the new input system but here is my attempt:

```
public class crawlScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    CapsuleCollider playerCol;
    float originalHeight;
    public float reducedHeight;
    bool crawl = false; 
    void Start()
    {
        playerCol= GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        originalHeight= playerCol.height;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (crawl)
        {
            OnCrouch();
        }
        else if (!crawl)
        {
            GoUp(); 
        }
    }

    public void OnCrouch() 
    {
       
        playerCol.height= reducedHeight;
    }

    void GoUp()
    { 
      
        playerCol.height = originalHeight;
    }

    public void OnCrawl()
    {
        crawl= true;
    }
```

And added this to the `InputManager` class:

```
groundMovement.Crawl.performed += _ => crawlscript.OnCrawl();
```

Comment: Let me try to restate your question: you are trying to designate a button that when pressed, toggles the player's crouch state?

Comment: Yes, but not crouch state, I want the player to crawl (laying on his stomach) and move on that state. But using the new input system for taking the inputs.

Comment: not only triggers the state of the player, I have no idea how to make the player on the position of crawling.

Comment: What have you already tried? How did the results of what you tried differ from the outcome you needed? Please share your research effort.

Comment: I edited the question and added my attempt.

Comment: I've lost track of how many questions I've seen over the last few days that have `isGrounded` as a variable. I'm wondering if there's some big group project or competition going on. Is it a hackathon? I'd like to participate!

Comment: well, the issue here has nothing to do with isGrounded! sure you can participate.

Comment: You're wanting the least code change possible, but I'd encourage you to look at state machines for your player movement. Each state, like jumping, walking, crawling, etc. would have its own set of exit conditions and all the logic for when you transition states would live in the state itself. Can your character go from a crawl to a jump, or do they need to stand first? Can they go from a run to a crawl or do they need to walk first? State machines give you a really good framework to cleanly define what is allowable from which starting condition.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. The issue is that I'm not so comfortable using the new input system that's why I wanted the least code change, because I don't want things to be missed up and cracked.

Comment: but you are right, there are certain things that can't be done in each state, such as jumping when crawling..

Answer (score 1):

You will need to

1. Create a public boolean variable for whether the player is crawling or not, because this will almost certainly be needed in the future by this script or other scripts.
2. Create a crawling animation
3. Create two functions for enabling and disabling crawl, that will toggle the animation, change the players walk speed, and do other things that you may want to add (like toggle the visibility of any objects in the player's hands until they get back up).

The code should look something like this:

```
public String crawlkey = "left shift";
public bool iscrawling = false;

// put in Update()
if(!crawling){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(crawlkey)){
        iscrawling = true;
        handleCrawlStart();
    }
} else if(Input.GetKeyDown(crawlkey)){
    iscrawling = false;
    handleCrawlEnd;
}
```